# How to multiply a variable and round it on flutter

Tags: flutter, math, rounding

I try desperately to do a calculation and round up without the "." the figure but I can't, because it's for a transfer to Stripe which refuses decimals.
Thank you for your help

```
 var response = await StripeService.payWithNewCard(
    amount: '${((widget.mylist3)*100).round()}',
    currency: 'EUR'
```

Comment: Try double.parse(((widget.mylist3)*100).toStringAsFixed(0)) method instead of ((widget.mylist3)*100).round()

Comment: I have already tested and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `amount:` parameter takes int, and you are providing a string.

Correct solution would be :

```
...
    amount: (widget.mylist3)*100).round(),
...
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, it always gives me an error, is there not something to declare

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it does not work, it always gives me an error, is there not something to declare